# Script not running in modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got a script that changes the background when an anchor touches the top of the page.

https://jsfiddle.net/u9pexc4v/

```
var targetOffset = $("#anchor-point").offset().top;

var $w = $(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($w.scrollTop() > targetOffset) {
      $(".projectTitle").addClass("topper");

} else {
    $(".projectTitle").removeClass("topper");
       }
});
```

However, it does not work when it's inside the modal window.

https://jsfiddle.net/qhrmtass/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to attach the scroll event to the element that's scrolling.

```
$('.remodal').scroll(function () {

  console.log('Scrolling...');

  if ($('.remodal').scrollTop() > targetOffset) {
    $(".projectTitle").addClass("topper");
  } else {
    $(".projectTitle").removeClass("topper");
  }
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhrmtass/3/)

Comment: If I change the anchor to somewhere else `#anchor-point {
    top: 30%;}` it still changes color as if the anchor was `top:0;`.

Comment: When your offset variable is initializing, the modal isn't visible so I suspect it's getting set to 0. See update: http://jsfiddle.net/qhrmtass/7/